# R Read abbreviated month form a date that is not in English

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have a text file that includes dates, and want to convert it to a datatable.

Converting the dates such as 03-FEB-2011 can be done with

```
data$fecha <- as.Date(data$textDate , "%d-%b-%Y")
```

The problem is that the column is in Spanish, so I don't get Jan but Ene, or Aug but Ago. 
How can I change the locale so the %b abbreviation works for Spanish? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I think you should do `Sys.setlocale(locale = "en_US.UTF-8")` of course instead of `en_US.UTF-8` you have to use the right locale which you can find with `system("locale -a", intern = TRUE)`. Let me know if it works well.

Comment: which is `"es_ES.UTF-8"` in your case.

Comment: If you get "OS reports request to set locale to "LOCALE" cannot be honored". See https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server

Answer (score 9):

As my previous comment, here is a complete and tested answer. As I've said you have to set your `locale` to the one right for your data (in this case spanish).

The code that allows you to do that is the following:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale="es_ES.UTF-8")
```

you can see the complete list of available `locale`s with `system("locale -a", intern = TRUE)` (not sure if it works well on Windows systems).

Here is an example:

```
x <- c("03-Ago-2011", "21-Ene-2012")
as.Date(x, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
[1] "2011-08-03" "2012-01-21"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you can't add locales to your OS,

```
> Sys.setlocale(locale = "es")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(locale = "es") :
OS reports request to set locale to "es" cannot be honored
```

the package [readr()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/vignettes/locales.html) has ways to specify and even create locales:

```
> library(readr) 
> parse_date("31 DICIEMBRE 2011","%d %B %Y",locale=locale("es"))
[1] "2011-12-31"
```

Comment: Also try `Sys.setlocale(locale = "English")` or `Sys.setlocale(locale = "C")`.