# Incorrect Date Format In R

Tags: r, date, format

I try to change the format of `"20FEB12:00:00:00"` to Date and R gives me `"NA"`
Don´t know what I am doing wrong:

```
strptime("20FEB12:00:00:00", "%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")
```

Thanks!

Comment: `strptime("20FEB12:00:00:00", "%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S") [1] "2012-02-20 EST"` Double-check for typos.

Comment: I try but I get the same:                                                                                     x <- "20FEB12:00:00:00"
strptime(x, format="%d%b%y:%T")                                                                                    [1] NA :S

Comment: There may be some issue with your session/version/OS, because your original code works fine.

Comment: Bufff Ok, at least the code is ok, thanks to check with me!                                                 I can not do the "check" to your answer.. :/

Comment: The code works for me too.  The description for "%b" is "Abbreviated month name in the current locale on this platform".  When you run `Sys.getlocale()`, does it return a place where "FEB" represents the 2nd month?

Comment: Most likely the problem is with the `locale`. The abbreviated name you are using are in Spanish. There was ax exactly similar question days ago. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057148/r-read-abbreviated-month-form-a-date-that-is-not-in-english/32068524#32068524) is that post with a solution of mine that should do your job.

Comment: Sorry If I am a bit confused I have never seen this before... uhmmm if I run the Sys.getlocale() I get......          "LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252"

Comment: Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(locale = "es_ES.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "es_ES.UTF-8" cannot be honored

Comment: As @SabDeM recommended in the other post, try `Sys.setlocale(locale = "en_US.UTF-8")`.  Are you trying to match Spanish or English months?  I can't tell from "FEB".  In your dataset, what string is used to represent the 1st and 12th month?

Comment: English months. I try with Sys.setlocale(locale = "en_US.UTF-8")

Comment: and while you're at it,  try  the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 0):

Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME",locale = "C")