# converting strings to Datetime objects

Tags: r, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string in this format `12 Mar 1995` in a datetime object. I'm using the `as.Date` function, it works pretty well but, if I try to convert the string `18 Dec 1856` the function returns me NA. I tried changing different parts of the string and I discovered that some month abbreviation do not work. For instance, if I try to convert `18 Dec 1856` or `18 Jul 1856` it doesn't work, but if I want to convert `18 Mar 1956` or `18 May 1956` it works. What am I doing wrong?
Here is the code that I'm using:

`myDate="18 Dec 1956"
as.Date(myDate, format="%d %b %Y")`

Comment: The `%b` part of the format is locale-specific. If you are working on a system with Italian or other encoding, the English abbreviations will (mostly) not be interpreted correctly. Maybe try changing the locale as per this question where somebody was trying to read Spanish months in a US language locale - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057148/r-read-abbreviated-month-form-a-date-that-is-not-in-english

Comment: Thank you! Now it works, I wasted an entire day on this