# I can't make new column with paste R

Tags: r, dataframe

i have code and i cant make data in one column(problem in photos):

```r
dane <- read.csv2("dane-ceny.csv")
str(dane)
head(dane)

d<-dane[dane$region=="MALOPOLSKIE",c(3,4,6)]
dim(dane)
d$data<-as.Date(paste(d$rok,d$mies,"01",sep="-"),"%Y-%b-%d")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32057148/r-read-abbreviated-month-form-a-date-that-is-not-in-english

Comment: Please do not (try to) post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers, it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/), and you are asking everybody to transcribe data you have. Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Try using `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "de_DE")`  - change for your country, for more, read here : https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format=` string is correct, but I think maydin's link to a question whose answers include `Sys.setlocale(.)` is likely going to be the best approach. It might help to reproduce your working environment if you post what `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")` returns.

Here's some sample data, and my guess at the locale:

```r
d <- structure(list(rok = c("2017", "2018", "2018", "2019"), mies = c("sty", "lut", "wrz", "gru")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
d
#    rok mies
# 1 2017  sty
# 2 2018  lut
# 3 2018  wrz
# 4 2019  gru

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Polish")
# [1] "Polish_Poland.1250"
as.Date(paste(d$rok, d$mies, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%b-%d")
# [1] "2017-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-09-01" "2019-12-01"
```

As a workaround, or if this is incomplete and does not work for some of them,you can make a vector of all of your abbreviated months and then `match` your `$mies` against it. I'm going to guess Polish (informed via https://web.library.yale.edu/cataloging/months), which leads me to:

```r
month.abb.polish <- c("sty", "lut", "mar", "kwi", "maj", "cze", "lip", "sie", "wrz", "paź", "lis", "gru") # note 1

### this portion is just to prove that it works even if locale is wrong
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United States.1252")
# [1] "English_United States.1252"
as.Date(paste(d$rok, d$mies, "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%b-%d")
# [1] NA NA NA NA

### this is the workaround
paste(d$rok, match(d$mies, month.abb.polish), "01", sep = "-")
# [1] "2017-1-01"  "2018-2-01"  "2018-9-01"  "2019-12-01"
as.Date(paste(d$rok, match(d$mies, month.abb.polish), "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2017-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-09-01" "2019-12-01"
```

Note:

1. I do not speak Polish, so my guess at `"paź"` (and any of the other months) may not be quite right; and in fact, I may have inferred incorrectly and this is a different language altogether ... my apologies. The point of the "workaround" part of the answer, though, is that it doesn't matter what locale is set, nor if the abbreviations are actually technically correct: all it requires is that you know what abbreviations *in the dataset* correspond with which month-numbers. *This* solution is a one-for-one, so if the data is inconsistent and uses different abbreviations for the same month, then a different approach would be necessary.

   Multiple candidates could be handled as a lookup table. This version of `month.abb.polish` has more than one candidate for each month-number (I arbitrarily added `"jan"` and `"feb"` as two english variants, to fill it out, plus provided two abbreviations for "październik".

   ```r
   month.abb.polish <- c("sty"=1, "jan"=1, "lut"=2, "feb"=2, "mar"=3, "kwi"=4, "maj"=5, "cze"=6, "lip"=7, "sie"=8, "wrz"=9, "paz"=10, "pa?"=10, "lis"=11, "gru"=12)
   month.abb.polish[d$mies]
   # sty lut wrz gru 
   #   1   2   9  12 
   paste(d$rok, month.abb.polish[d$mies], "01", sep = "-")
   # [1] "2017-1-01"  "2018-2-01"  "2018-9-01"  "2019-12-01"
   as.Date(paste(d$rok, month.abb.polish[d$mies], "01", sep = "-"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
   # [1] "2017-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-09-01" "2019-12-01"
   ```

Comment: Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Polish") it helped, thanks! but i have anodher problem, with polish letters in R studio-I can't use it. $mies with polish letter "paź" isn't loading<NA>. And second question, i have to put Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Polish") every time when i close and open R studio?

Comment: See [`?.First`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html) for options including `~/.Rprofile` for loading something every time you start R.

Comment: it works! THANKS! But how about Polish characters?